# how do i fix? Error while enabling Quick Shop

Tags: minecraft, bukkit

i installed Quick Shop with all the plugins below and whenever i try to start the server the plugin doesn't work i tried using SPM(SimplePluginManager) too but no luck

my plugins (21): antiRedstoneClock, AuthMe, DiscordSRV, Essentials, EssentialsChat, GoldenCrates, GriefPrevention, LuckPerms, NexEngine, PlaceholderAPI, ProtocolLib, QuickShop*, SilkSpawners, SkinsRestorer, skRayFall, Skript, StackMob, Vault, ViaVersion, WorldEdit, WorldGuard

Here's the error i get when i start the server:

````
[14:23:10 ERROR]: Error occurred while enabling QuickShop v4.4 (Is it up to date?)
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'org.bukkit.configuration.file.YamlConfiguration org.bukkit.configuration.file.YamlConfiguration.loadConfiguration(java.io.InputStream)'
        at org.maxgamer.QuickShop.Util.MsgUtil.loadCfgMessages(MsgUtil.java:48) ~[?:?]
        at org.maxgamer.QuickShop.QuickShop.reloadConfig(QuickShop.java:344) ~[?:?]
        at org.maxgamer.QuickShop.QuickShop.onEnable(QuickShop.java:107) ~[?:?]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin.setEnabled(JavaPlugin.java:263) ~[patched_1.16.5.jar:git-Paper-774]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader.enablePlugin(JavaPluginLoader.java:370) ~[patched_1.16.5.jar:git-Paper-774]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.enablePlugin(SimplePluginManager.java:500) ~[patched_1.16.5.jar:git-Paper-774]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_16_R3.CraftServer.enablePlugin(CraftServer.java:518) ~[patched_1.16.5.jar:git-Paper-774]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_16_R3.CraftServer.enablePlugins(CraftServer.java:432) ~[patched_1.16.5.jar:git-Paper-774]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.MinecraftServer.loadWorld(MinecraftServer.java:594) ~[patched_1.16.5.jar:git-Paper-774]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.DedicatedServer.init(DedicatedServer.java:298) ~[patched_1.16.5.jar:git-Paper-774]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.MinecraftServer.w(MinecraftServer.java:1069) ~[patched_1.16.5.jar:git-Paper-774]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.MinecraftServer.lambda$a$0(MinecraftServer.java:291) ~[patched_1.16.5.jar:git-Paper-774]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831) [?:?]
[14:23:10 INFO]: [QuickShop] Disabling QuickShop v4.4
[14:23:10 ERROR]: Error occurred while disabling QuickShop v4.4 (Is it up to date?)
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.maxgamer.QuickShop.Shop.ShopManager.clear()" because "this.shopManager" is null
        at org.maxgamer.QuickShop.QuickShop.onDisable(QuickShop.java:413) ~[?:?]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin.setEnabled(JavaPlugin.java:265) ~[patched_1.16.5.jar:git-Paper-774]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader.disablePlugin(JavaPluginLoader.java:405) ~[patched_1.16.5.jar:git-Paper-774]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.disablePlugin(SimplePluginManager.java:533) ~[patched_1.16.5.jar:git-Paper-774]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader.enablePlugin(JavaPluginLoader.java:374) ~[patched_1.16.5.jar:git-Paper-774]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.enablePlugin(SimplePluginManager.java:500) ~[patched_1.16.5.jar:git-Paper-774]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_16_R3.CraftServer.enablePlugin(CraftServer.java:518) ~[patched_1.16.5.jar:git-Paper-774]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_16_R3.CraftServer.enablePlugins(CraftServer.java:432) ~[patched_1.16.5.jar:git-Paper-774]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.MinecraftServer.loadWorld(MinecraftServer.java:594) ~[patched_1.16.5.jar:git-Paper-774]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.DedicatedServer.init(DedicatedServer.java:298) ~[patched_1.16.5.jar:git-Paper-774]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.MinecraftServer.w(MinecraftServer.java:1069) ~[patched_1.16.5.jar:git-Paper-774]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.MinecraftServer.lambda$a$0(MinecraftServer.java:291) ~[patched_1.16.5.jar:git-Paper-774]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831) [?:?]```
````

Comment: You will have to contact the creator of this plugin with the stacktrace, we cannot help you because we cannot modify the source code.

Comment: I suggest you to upgrade the plugin in [v5](https://www.spigotmc.org/resources/62575/) and if it appear again, just report it to [quickshop support](https://github.com/Ghost-chu/QuickShop-Reremake/issues)

Answer (score 1):

The `org.bukkit.configuration.file.YamlConfiguration.loadConfiguration(java.io.InputStream)` method has been deprecated for over 3 years and was removed on may 14th 2017 in [this commit](https://hub.spigotmc.org/stash/projects/SPIGOT/repos/bukkit/commits/f2a9b248754b4fd91c0ae69d659a8bbf64ed4929#src/main/java/org/bukkit/configuration/file/YamlConfiguration.java). You'll have to contact the plugin developer to replace the deprecated method, or you'll have to fix this issue in the sourcecode of this plugin, or you'll have to re-add the method to your Bukkit server. The last two options require Java knowledge. In the current state, the plugin is simply not compatible with your server software.